solving Thevenin equivalent circuit

I only learned thevenin with simple circuits. How do I go about finding R_th?

What do you mean "terminals that are not connected to each other"?

FWIW this is one of those problems where you stare at it for a few minutes and then do your calculations on a postage stamp.  The trick to finding Rth is realizing thar, with voltage sources shorted and current opened, what's left (in this special case) is a balanced bridge. The 10 ohm resistor in parallel with the current source can be ignored.  Then find the voltage at the node above the current source. The fast way to do it is to find the Norton equivalents of the 3 components on the left and of the 4 on the left.  Add the current sources and find the equivalent parallel resistance.

Looking at the circuit, the load resistor \$R_L\$ should be connected across nodes a and b. For maximum power transfer, the load resistor should be equal to the Thevenin resistance \$R_{th}\$ as seen between a and b with the load resistor disconnected.
Hint:
For finding Thevenin resistance, open circuit current sources and short circuit voltage sources. Leave dependent sources as they are. Assume load resistor is not connected yet.
With that, 20Ω and 20Ω resistors would be in parallel and become 10Ω. The 5A current source would be open circuited. All resistors would be 10Ω resistors.
To find \$R_{th}\$, connect a 1A current source between nodes a and b. Connect node b to GND. Use nodal analysis to obtain voltage at node a. That voltage is the Thevenin resistance.

Thank you. That worked. But don't we only use test charge if and only if there's a dependent source in the circuit?

The 1A current source method works if there is a dependent current source or a dependent voltage source in the circuit. You would use supernodes or super meshes as required. It is used in all cases if there is no clear combination of series or parallel resistors in the circuit.
